# Why does my table have cropped corners?

Tags: tables

I was trying to use the tabular environment and noticed something strange so I increased the line width and then it became obvious that the corners of the table are cropped.

This would be the code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }
            \hline
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

And this would be the output:

[image]

Comment: That's expected.

Comment: @egreg Do you mean this "feature" is *intended* by design, or do you just mean that you knew already it was so ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The "strange" corners are fixed by package `array`, see section "[2.1 Handling of rules](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/tools/array.pdf)".

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{1mm}
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{18pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}

\begin{document}
    \begin{center}
        \begin{tabular}{ |c|c|c| }
            \hline
            1 & 2 & 3 \\
            \hline
        \end{tabular}
    \end{center}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]