# How does array.sty handle vertical rules?

Tags: tables, border

**Section 2.1** of the `array.sty` documentation explains that rules are "placed between columns or rows thereby enlarging the table". I'm interested in *how* it is done for vertical rules as I can't reproduce it with Plain TeX. I tried to read the source code and the documentation, however `array.sty` is complex and it is hard sometimes to understand what is happening.

I thought first that the content between columns (like rules) were in a "fake" column (something like `First column & \vline & Second column`. However, the definition of `\multicolumn` tells me that it is not the case.

If I had to produce in Plain TeX a table with "perfect" rule corners like `array.sty` does, how would I do it ? This would really help me understand the underlying mechanism.

**Related questions :**

- [Why does my table have cropped corners?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/377462/why-does-my-table-have-cropped-corners)
- [Weird corners with \cline](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505789/weird-corners-with-cline)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\newdimen\tabcolsep
\tabcolsep6pt


% latex |c|c|

\halign{%
% first col has 2 |
\strut\vrule\hskip\tabcolsep\hfil\ignorespaces%
#%
\unskip\hfil\hskip\tabcolsep\vrule\hskip\tabcolsep&%
% later columns have tabcolsep|tabscolsep at the right edge of the column
\strut\hfil\ignorespaces%
#%
\unskip\hfil\hskip\tabcolsep\vrule\cr%
\noalign{\hrule}%
aaa & bbb \cr
\noalign{\hrule}%
1&2\cr
\noalign{\hrule}%
}

\bye
```

Comment: Fantastic! Is there any reason why you would use `\hskip` instead of `\kern` in this case?

Comment: @JDMCreator because you asked what latex does:-) Also it's `\tabcolsep` not `\tabskip` (which is a tex primitve I didn't mean to over-write that, I edited the code to fix)

Comment: It is indeed what I asked! I was just wondering if the use of `\hskip` in LaTeX was a deliberate decision or not.

Comment: @JDMCreator I don't think so but hard to be sure, array.sty does it that way as the base tabular code in the latex format does in that way and it's done it that way since Leslie Lamport first drafted it in the mid 1980s so it's easy to say how things are a lot harder sometimes to say why...